# trying to port project in overleaf.com to local drive using latexmk

Tags: beamer, overleaf

I have a project on overleaf that is structured as a number of directories, all sharing a common preamble with the common look.

Each folder contains main.tex, and creates a single pdf.
The source code uses the beamer class. This code works in overleaf, but when downloaded to my computer, using latexmk to build, it is failing:

```
    \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
    \input{Preamble/commands.tex}
    \title[]{test}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{withoutheadline}
    
    \begin{frame}{Slide 1}
      Testing testing 123
      
      $O(n)$
    \end{frame}
    \end{withoutheadline}
    
    \begin{frame}{Slide 2}
      Test 2
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

I will append the entire command file for completeness, but the line failing is:

```
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

The complete file is:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{series=\bfseries\itshape}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %  fontenc is used to fix the bug for greek letter \Delta
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

%% customization of beamer environments
%% copyright notice
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=2.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\copyright notice\vspace{-1ex}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=2.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}{\insertshorttitle}\vspace{-1ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
%% logo banner
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \raisebox{-\paperheight+10pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \makebox[\paperwidth][l]{%
            \hspace{1cm}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Preamble/logo.pdf}%
        }%
    }%
}
%% create an environment called "withoutheadline" to save space on content slides
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{withoutheadline}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
    \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        \raisebox{-\paperheight+\headheight+10pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
            \makebox[\paperwidth][l]{%
                \hspace{.5cm}\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Preamble/Logo.pdf}%
            }%
        }%
    }
}{}
\makeatother
%% create an environment called "withoutheadlinelogoright" in which the logo is located on the right
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{withoutheadlinelogoright}{
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}[default]
    \def\beamer@entrycode{\vspace*{-\headheight}}
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
        \raisebox{-\paperheight+\headheight+17pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
            \makebox[\paperwidth][r]{%
                \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Preamble/Logo.pdf}\hspace{.5cm}%
            }%
        }%
    }
}{}
\makeatother
%% set up beginning pages for each section and subsection
\newif\ifSectionTitlePage
\newcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagefalse}

\newcommand\AllSectionsWithTitlePage{%
  \SectionTitlePagetrue
  \renewcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagetrue}%
}
\newcommand\AllSectionsWithoutTitlePage{%
  \SectionTitlePagefalse
  \renewcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagefalse}%
}
\newcommand\NextSectionWithTitlePage{\SectionTitlePagetrue}
\newcommand\NextSectionWithoutTitlePage{\SectionTitlePagefalse}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \ifSectionTitlePage
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
  \fi
  \SectionTitlePagedefault
}
% subsection page
\AtBeginSubsection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubsection\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}
\AllSectionsWithTitlePage
% pagenumber
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
%% enable options for switching theme colors
\definecolor{CraneYellow}{RGB}{252,187,6}
\definecolor{CraneBlack}{RGB}{4,6,76}
\definecolor{CustomBlue}{RGB}{51,51,178}
\definecolor{CustomGreen}{RGB}{50, 205, 50}

\newcommand{\setframecolorExtra}{   
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=CraneBlack,bg=CraneYellow}}
\newcommand{\setframecolorDeep}{    
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=CraneBlack,bg=CustomGreen!50}}
\newcommand{\setframecolorAct}{
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=CraneBlack,bg=CustomBlue!50}}



\usepackage{soul} %for \ul underline command which wraps text while underlining 
\newcommand{\mystep}[1]{{\vspace{2mm}\noindent\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myhigh}[1]{\textit{\ul{#1}}}
% Robotics Math
\newcommand{\realfield}{\hbox{I \kern -.4em R}}
\newcommand {\mb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % all replaced
\newcommand {\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\uvecf}[3]{\,^{#1}\hat{\mathbf{#2}}_{#3}}
\newcommand{\T}{^{\top}}  %shortcut for transpose
\newcommand*{\diameter}{\bigcirc\kern-0.95em\diagup}
\newcommand{\rmd}{\textrm{d}}  %shortcut for derivative
% Control Math
\newcommand{\ddtn}[2]{\dfrac{\rmd^{#2} #1}{\rmd t^{#2}}}
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\dfrac{\rmd #1}{\rmd t}}
\newcommand{\lap}[1]{\mathcal{L}\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\lapinv}[1]{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[#1\right]}
%% Remarks and Conclusions index setup
\newcounter{remark}[section]
\newcounter{remarkSavedIndex}[section]
\newcommand{\remarkIndex}{\refstepcounter{remark}\textit{Remark \theremark}}
\newcommand{\remarkSaveIndex}{\setcounter{remarkSavedIndex}{\value{remark}}}
\newcommand{\remarkLoadIndex}{\setcounter{remark}{\value{remarkSavedIndex}}}
\newcounter{conclusion}[section]
\newcounter{conclusionSavedIndex}[section]
\renewcommand{\theconclusion}{\Roman{conclusion}}
\newcommand{\conclusionIndex}{\refstepcounter{conclusion}\textbf{Conclusion (\theconclusion)}}
\newcommand{\conclusionSaveIndex}{\setcounter{conclusionSavedIndex}{\value{conclusion}}}
\newcommand{\conclusionLoadIndex}{\setcounter{conclusion}{\value{conclusionSavedIndex}}}

%% Custom slide options
%% This code contains different options:
% 1. Extended set of slides (including deep dives and extra challenges), named Lect_X_extended
% 2. Lecture presenting slides (trimming off extra challenges), named Lect_X
% 3. Lecture presenting slides with bullet advancing mode, named Lect_X_pres

\ifdefined\slidePresentingMode
\else
    \newcommand\slidePresentingMode{1}
\fi

\newif\ifSlideExtra
\newif\ifSlideDeepDive
\newif\ifSlideBulletAdvance

\ifnum \slidePresentingMode=1
    \SlideExtratrue
    \SlideDeepDivetrue
    \SlideBulletAdvancefalse    
\fi

\ifnum \slidePresentingMode=2
    \SlideExtrafalse
    \SlideDeepDivefalse
    \SlideBulletAdvancefalse
\fi

\ifnum \slidePresentingMode=3
    \SlideExtrafalse
    \SlideDeepDivefalse
    \SlideBulletAdvancetrue
\fi

%% activate the following line to generate presenting slides as oppose to notes slide
\ifSlideBulletAdvance
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\fi



%% custom slide indices
% define an index for active learning act
\newcounter{activeLearn}
\newcommand{\activeLearnIndex}{\refstepcounter{activeLearn}In-class Exercise \#\theactiveLearn }
% define an index for deep dives
\newcounter{deepDive}
\newcommand{\deepDiveIndex}{\refstepcounter{deepDive}Deep Dive \#\thedeepDive }
% define an index for extra challenges
\newcounter{extraChallenge}
\newcommand{\extraChIndex}{\refstepcounter{extraChallenge}Extra Challenge \#\theextraChallenge }

%% table preamble
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% Dov's requests for common spacing commands on slides
\newcommand{\smallspace}{\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\bigspace}{\vspace{5mm}}

\institute{My Department\\My University}
% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\centering\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{Preamble/logo.png}
}
\author{Author Name}
\date{\today}
```

The error message is

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/soul/soul.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.212 \newcolumntype
                {C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

Comment: Overleaf is very good in hiding errors from users (or more generous to Overleaf: it makes it easy for users to ignore errors) and still producing output despite those errors (it configures TeX to press on despite errors, which will often result in a PDF, which may or may not have serious issues). Locally TeX systems are often configured to stop at the first error. Check the little button to the right of the "Recompile" button on Overleaf and see if it maybe reports the same error. Then fix all reported errors. Ideally the project will then compile on Overleaf and locally. ...

Comment: ... Another possible source of issues are different TeX Live/package versions on Overleaf and locally. So you may want to check if your TeX system is up to date and if you have selected the most recent version on Overleaf as well.

Comment: That all said, `\newcolumntype` is defined by the `array` package. So maybe adding `\usepackage{array}` will let your document compile again.

Comment: unrelated but at both overleaf and this site all files are utf-8 so delete `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

Answer (score 1):

The file as multiple errors which are reported on overleaf just as they are in a local tex installation.

See

https://www.overleaf.com/read/yqwnftmqfynt#522d04

Which has

[image]

so 8 errors reported in the log, which are also indicated by the red blobs on the error lines:

[image]

If I comment out

```
%\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Preamble/logo.pdf}%
```

Then it runs without error at both Overleaf and locally.

`\newcolumntype` comes from the array package, which is loaded via `colortbl` as `beamer` loads `xcolor` with the `table` option as you used the option

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
```

Unrelated but don't use

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

on UTF-8 encoded files. (Which is the encoding always used on this site, and on Overleaf)